# How to run Chrome Java script snippet script automatically on screen load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want automate login, after screen load through chrome javascript snippet.

Is there any way option available.

Comment: as this is for an automated test why aren't you using selenium?

Comment: Not automated test, Inorder to avoid login each time in website, I am trying to use snippet option provided by chrome devtools

Comment: Then why use the `automated-tests` tag? Same goes for `google-rich-snippets` they seem out of place

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no standard for login forms, so there isn't a standard solution which would work on *any* website. A bookmarklet or userscript which might log you in on site A might not work on site B. Have you tried a password manager with good browser integration?

Comment: Trying this for one site only which I use frequently, where login expired in 15 mins. In order to enter credentials frequently. if it is automated via chrome snippet, if snippet executed, after DOM load completed automatically when url is launched.

Comment: As I said: There is no standard for login forms. So when you can not show us the website you want to log into, then we might not be able to help you.